# Reset the session variable when the user leaves a specific page (Except refresh)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

First of all, sorry if this is a duplicate, I've searched and so far I found nothing.

So, when the user goes to "`fightzone1.php`", it launches a random fight.

```
$query=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM monsters ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
```

The monster's maximum health is in the database. But, his actual health is calculated like that :

```
$monster_actualhealth = ($data["monster_health"] -   $_SESSION['damage']);
```

- $Monster_actualhealth is the health of the monster.
- $data["monster_health"] is the maximum health of the monster, located in the database
- $_SESSION['damage'] is the damage the user will inflict to the monster.

`<form action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Attack the creature" name="attacking"></form>`

With this button, the user is able to deal damages to the monster

```
     if (isset($_POST['attacking'])) { 
        if (!isset($_SESSION['last_post'])) { 
     $_SESSION['last_post'] = 0;
  }
  $currtime = time(); 
  if ($currtime  > ($_SESSION['last_post'] + 2)) {
     $_SESSION['last_post'] = $currtime; 

      $randomdamageperso = rand(5, 12);
        $query->execute();
        $query->CloseCursor();
      $_SESSION['damage'] = ( $_SESSION['damage'] + $randomdamageperso);
     $monster_actualhealth = ($data["monster_health"] -   $_SESSION['damage']);
      echo "You inflicted " . $randomdamageperso . "  !";
           echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1.5" />';

}
}
}
```

(I deleted some text to make the script easy to understand and less messy, he is working fine but don't worry if i forgot to remove 1 or 2 elements.)

(Let's call `$_SESSION['damage']` just `$damage` from now on)
So, basically;  it adds a random number into `$damage` (Between 5 and 12) and it add the number to the previous number of `$damage`, making it bigger. So, for example, if `$damage` is 12 and the monster health is 35, the actual monster health will be 23.

Now, the tricky part is that the user can just leave the page, go get some heal, and comes back to this page. Yes, the monster will change and it will be another one, but the $_SESSION['damage'] will stay the same, making the monster loose health when the fight has not begun yet.

As you can see in my script, there is echo making the page refresh to actually refresh the display of the monster's health, so the user can keep track of the fight. (It show how much he inflicted, and after 1.5 seconds the text disappear and it refresh.)

I can't do some javascript with the "unload" function, because the button will refresh the page, and I don't want the `$damage` to go to 0 when I press the button.

I tried to make everything clear, so thanks for taking the time to help me!

**EDIT :**

```
<?php
        $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM fightmonster WHERE player_id='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'  ORDER BY time_stamp desc limit 1");
        $query->execute();
        $result=$query->fetch();
                $query->CloseCursor();
if (isset($result['id'])){
echo "unfinished business!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to destroy a specific session name you can use [unset](http://php.net/unset)()

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

BUT, in your case, using SESSIONS for this is a bad idea.

You should use a fight table where you save the user id, the monster id, the start time in [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)() format and the damage done and when the user gets back simply check if the user has started a battle with that monster or not. When the damage reaches 0 you delete the fight row or keep it for history purpose.

The nice thing about this is you can also increment the monsters health with time so if the user comes back 5 minutes later, the monster could have healed 1 or 2 points.

*Sessions were not created to hold temp vars in an active environment like this. They are used to store inactive vars and keep them from page to page.*

> So in light of this explanation, you would be better off:
>
> 1. Create a fight table {id, monster_id, player_id, damage, start_time}
> 2. Save the damage made to the fight table
> 3. **Obtional** Create a cron script that decrements monster damage based on start time for fights with a damage level smaller than the max health of the monster
> 4. Resume the fight with the monster when the player is back by checking if the player has already started one before he left

Just an idea, while the user is away, there could be a random chance for the monster to pick up a new weapon or armour or cast a magic spell or even enter a rage state that would increase his attack or defence. So the player might think twice before leaving an unfinished battle lol If the monster gets fully healed he runs away.

In any case, a table will offer more options than a very unstable session. (not that it's impossible to get working) It's just not the most efficient way of doing this because the session will kill it self at some point losing all the data with it. Using tables will open your game to new possibility like fight history, fight statistics and such.

---

But if you really want to use SESSIONS and your stick to this idea, You can bind the damage value to the monsters ID or event ID so that the session will not corrupt the start of a new event/monster fight.

```
$_SESSION[damage][555][12]
$_SESSION[time_stamp][555][123456789]
```

Where 555 is the monster id and 12 is the total damage and 123456789 is the time stamp the fight started.

But I still think this is a bad idea lol

---

Based on your comment below you just need a simple check

```
// SQL examle    
// SELECT * FROM fight WHERE player_id='$_SESSION[id]' and max_health<damage ORDER BY start_time desc limit 1

if (isset($result->id)){
    echo "unfinished business!";
}else{
    echo "starting a new battle!";
}
```

The above is just a concept. you can figure out the right way to implement this.

Comment: Wow, that's actually a very good answer, thanks you ! I'll need your help for something now i guess. So, i created a table "fightmonster" where there is the fight id, the player id, the monster name and the monster life. The problem is that every time i refresh, another battle is created. How can i make "if a player_id  is found with the same id as $_SESSION['id'], then" ? I need it to not pick a random monster if the user is already in battle.

Comment: No problem. Juste added a new section to my answer. It's only a concept thought. But it should get you on the right track. please accept answer ;-) Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer ! Sorry, i'm very bad with MySQL, so i got another question. i tried to do like you told me (look at my edit in the original post) but i don't know where you got that $result from.. Tried to figure it out, no clues. Thanks for helping me ;)

Comment: The $result would be the return of the DB query. in your case it would present it self like this $result->id;

Comment: Hi. I'm very sorry for all the questions and the time, but i had to write the code. So now, everything is good, there is a table named "fightm" with temporary rows and everything i needed. The only problem is that i still don't know the answer to the main question : how can i know when the user is away ? How do i know the user did not left the fight to heal and came back ?

Comment: Everytime a user pushes the button you can use strtotime("now") and update the time_stamp in the table. Then it's only a math problem. $ago = strtotime("now")-$timestamp; $time = date('i', $ago); if ($time>=2){echo "it's been 2 minutes ...";}

Comment: I think this is starting to get a little messy. Post a new question for the next one lol I will drop in if needed ;-)

Comment: You're right, i should create a new one. The problem is that leaving the battle and going to heal takes only 15/20 seconds, and i can't just limit the battle to 15/20 seconds. I'm going to create a new question, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Np I will take a look into it. Just make sure your question in clear and formatted in a way that can be useful to others so you gain reputation in the process ;-)